# Selecting the highest ranking that is output from a function in R

Tags: r

I have 2 little functions to look at what people ate. Each row is a meal:

```
df <- data.frame(food1=c('fruit', 'twinkies', 'meat'), food2=c('fruit', 'diary', 'meat'), food3=c('fruit', 'meat', 'skittles'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# > df
#     food1 food2 food3
# 1    fruit fruit  fruit
# 2 twinkies diary  meat
# 3     meat  meat  skittles
```

I'd like to rank the foods depending on what people ate, and save the rankings in a list, then later glue back to the dataframe:

```
# since we will have levels of 1 and 2, we will collect the levels in a list
categories_list<- list('fruit'=c(),
                             'dairy'=c(),
                             'meat'=c()
                       )
```

Please don't kick me too hard for how poorly these 2 functions were written. My question really is this:

I can run my functions against one row at a time, e.g. against `df[1,]` but I want to run against the whole dataframe at once. I can't seem to vectorize these functions appropriately. Further, the highest rank should win -- and I need to bind this information back to the dataframe.

Here are the functions:

```
## LEVEL 1: did they eat fruit/dairy/meat for food1? Score them a 1 for whatever food1 they ate.
get_Level_1 <- function(categories_list, a_vec){
  for(name in names(categories_list)){
    if(name == a_vec$food1){
      categories_list[[name]] <- c(categories_list[[name]], 1)
    }
  }
  return(categories_list)}


# LEVEL 2: testing to see if they ate fruit, dairy or meat, and that's all they ate. If so, give them a 2 for that food.
get_Level_2 <- function(categories_list, a_vec){
  for(name in names(categories_list)){
    all_cats <- c(a_vec$food1, a_vec$food2, a_vec$food3)
    for(name in names(categories_list)){
      if(  (name %in% all_cats) & (length(setdiff(all_cats, name))==0)  ){ 
        categories_list[[name]] <- c(categories_list[[name]], 2)
      }
    }
    return(categories_list)}}
```

These all run fine, as expected:

```
get_Level_1(categories_list, df[1,])
get_Level_1(categories_list, df[2,])
get_Level_1(categories_list, df[3,])
get_Level_2(categories_list, df[1,])
get_Level_2(categories_list, df[2,])
get_Level_2(categories_list, df[3,])
```

But notice, if you run these lines, the first row gets both a 1 and 2 for 'fruit'. I want the highest ranking to win, e.g., 2.

Ultimately I'd like to get the output looking like this:

```
> df
     fruit dairy meat
1      2 
2 
3                  1
```

Other stuff:

- I know it's kinda funky. But this is a simplified version where there are a ton more small classification functions that all spit out rankings. The highest output always wins.
- Maybe the idea of using a list is a bad idea? Originally, I wanted to use a list so I could just stick numbers in it, e.g.

  $fruit
  [1] 1 2

and I could select the largest number that way.

- The problem is really broken down in 2 parts. First, how to run across all rows, and then second, how to take the list output and somehow append to the dataframe. I can't seem to decouple these two steps in a good way.
- I've tried `lapply` all over, then messed around with `dplyr`. Various combinations of filtering and selecting haven't worked, because I need to collect a lot of rankings first. I tried taking out the whole list part. I tried a ton of things...and I'm stuck.

Comment: I would add a column for each ranking. Your `get_Level_1` function would be replaced by `df$Level_1 = ifelse(df$food1 == "fruit", 1, 0)`. Similarly add a column `Level_2`. Then your final rank (letting the highest one win) is `df$high_rank = with(df, pmax(Level_1, Level_2, ...))`.

Comment: I guess I was misunderstanding, I was trying to rank meals, not foods. I think it can still work (and be vectorized), but it's different than my first comment. `pmax` will be helpful. You would be updating food_rank columns with something like `df$fruit_rank = pmax(df$fruit_rank, get_Level_X(...))`

Comment: Why isn't row 2 a (0, 2, 2) because there is diary and meat? In addition, can each food have one score only? Otherwise, row 3 should be (2, 2, 0) right?

Comment: `(length(setdiff(all_cats, name))==0)` is a way to check for uniqueness of foods appearing in a certain row. Yes, one score only, the highest score wins. Row 3 shouldn't have any '2' since no food was unique. But meat gets a  '1' since they ate it for food1. It's weird, I know.